# pygame window not responding when clicked

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame for interface display and controller input on a project I'm working on. Currently everything works sufficiently well so this isn't a major concern, but if it accidentally happens during actual use there might be some problems so I'd like to fix it possible.

When I run my code, the pygame window appears, displays, and updates exactly as expected. However, if I click on it or it gains focus some other way the window freezes and becomes (Not Responding). The code itself continues running, including the thread that is responsible for updating the display, until I close the window so Python itself is still running fine, but the window stops working.

My code for the update loop is here, in all its really ugly glory:

```
    while(1):
        print "thread is fine"
        pygame.event.pump()

        if LOV_Flag == 1:
            videoColor = (255, 0, 0)
        else:
            videoColor = (0, 255, 0)

        # Refresh the screen and redraw components

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pulseLabel = pulseFont.render("Pulse: ", 1, (0, 0, 0))
        videoLabel = videoFont.render("Video: ", 1, (0, 0, 0))
        motorsLabel = labelFont.render("Motors", 1, (0, 0, 0))
        motorLabel = captionFont.render("L         R", 1, (0, 0, 0))
        armLabel = captionFont.render("Arm", 1, (0, 0, 0))
        gripperLabel = captionFont.render("Gripper", 1, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(motorsLabel, (55, 50))
        screen.blit(motorLabel, (60, 75))
        screen.blit(pulseLabel, (300, 19))
        screen.blit(videoLabel, (300, 45))
        screen.blit(armLabel, (250, 75))
        screen.blit(gripperLabel, (235, 255))
        leftBar = (50, 200 - drive.getSpeed()[0], 25, drive.getSpeed()[0])
        rightBar = (100, 200 - drive.getSpeed()[1], 25, drive.getSpeed()[1])
        armBar = (250, 200 - (100 * arm.report()), 25, (100 * arm.report()))
        upperArmBar = (250, 200 - (100 * arm.reportUp()), 25, 2) # 100 is the value on the bar
        lowerArmBar = (250, 200 - (100 * arm.reportDown()), 25, 2) # 135 (65) is the value on the bar
        gripperBar = (212, 225, (100 * hand.report()), 25)
        leftGripperBar = (212 + (100 * hand.reportClosed()), 225, 2, 25)
        rightGripperBar = (212 + (100 * hand.reportOpen()), 225, 2, 25)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), leftBar, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), rightBar, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), armBar, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), upperArmBar, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), lowerArmBar, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), gripperBar, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), leftGripperBar, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), rightGripperBar, 0)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, pulseColor, [370, 32], 10)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, videoColor, [370, 58], 10)
        pygame.display.update()

        time.sleep(0.1)
        if killFlag:
            return
```

An [image](http://puu.sh/faEar/198b61aa52.PNG) for how the window looks, in case that helps you understand the code better.

Comment: Change `time.sleep(0.1)` to `pygame.time.sleep(100)`. Let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: Get rid of `return`. There is no function.

Comment: `pygame.time.sleep(100)` caused an error "'module' object has no attribute 'sleep'" and the return is used to exit the thread's run() function. I probably have alternatives to return, but there is a function (just not shown) which the return works to exit.

Comment: I mean `pygame.time.delay(100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved this code to main instead of a thread, it works now. I did end up needing the pygame.event.pump() line, and I now use clock.tick() for rate control, but it's otherwise identical but moved. Apparently pygame just doesn't play well with threading.

Thanks for all the help though, the actual solution may have been discovered accidentally but having things to try kept me trying long enough to try the thing I didn't expect to work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't run the code you've posted to test myself, but there a few things I'd like to point out that might help. Firstly, that's not the right way to kill a program, at least not the way I know. What I use in pygame is:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

Is the time.sleep(1) at the end of your loop to try to control framerate? If so, you'd be much better served by utilizing a pygame clock. initialize a clock before your main loop as follows:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

Then within the main loop use this:

```
clock.tick(60)
```

What this does is set the program to run at your desired fps. In this case it's set to 60.

Lastly, i honestly don't know why your window would stop responding once it receives mouse input, but if that's indeed the culprit you could simply block mouse events. Try this before your while loop:

```
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEMOTION)
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)
```

This should disregard all input from your mouse, you won't even be able to see it over your window.

Comment: I've added `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit()` when all the threads return (I have them `join()` in the main function), though `sys.exit()` returns a "sys is not defined" error so maybe that's part of the problem.

Comment: I meant to do just one comment, but I keep hitting enter when I shouldn't. `clock.tick()` doesn't improve anything, I had already tried it. Trying to disable the mouse doesn't seem to change anything since the display isn't the active window anyway, and it stops responding even if I gain focus a different way. Sorry it isn't runnable, this is only a portion of the whole code which has dependencies on additional separate files, separate running programs, and some hardware. I imagine the solution would require work elsewhere, I was just hoping somebody knew where to look from this much.

Comment: you have to import system for sys.exit to work. You can disregard if it's not imported, i generally import it in my games. Also, i'm not entirely sure that pygame supports multi-threading, that may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The event queue is probably filled up and no more events can be handled, and thus the OS says the window is not responding.

You should clear the event queue by calling `pygame.event.clear()` if you're not interested in any events, but maybe you want to least handle `pygame.QUIT`, so calling `pygame.event.get()` (without an argument) will also do the trick.

Comment: I'm handling events in another thread of the same program, so that shouldn't be the issue, and trying to get() them in threads that don't need them has caused the main handler to miss them since they are removed from the queue. I am using pump() just in case, but it was having the issue before I put that in and it didn't go away afterwards either.

Comment: Could you try reading events in this thread only, and pass them to the main thread via a `Queue` (or some other threadsafe means)? Just a shoot in the dark....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is threads, I had the same problem, if I run pygame updates in a thread, it locks up when I change focus, if I run it without threads the same code works fine. The work around is to make sure 'pygame' is only called from your main original thread, and then other code can be in other threads, but anything related to pygame should all come from the main thread.  That worked for me anyway.